# Multidimensional Enumeration, how to avoid Code Macro Generation

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested

So I have a multidimensional list called Object, with n dimensions

I am performing a procedure for all the elements of this Object (which can be anything including other multidimensional lists)

So I began generating the following inductive way of enumerating the object

Case 1: 1-d (list)

```
i = 0
while(i < len(Object)):
    f(Object[i])
    i+=1
```

Case 2: 2-d (list inside list)

```
i = 0
while(i < len(Object)):
    j = 0 
    while(j < len(Object[i][j])):
         f(Object[i])
         j+=1
    i+=1
```

At this point it becomes intuitively obvious that the n dimensional object can be traversed through the following code

```
indexarray = [] #multi dimensional index structure
i = 0
while(i < n):
     indexarray.append(0)
     i+=1
#Prepared the indices

while(indexarray[0] < len(Object)):
    indexarray[1] = 0
    while(indexarray[1] < len(Object[indexarray[0]])):
        indexarray[2] = 0
        while(indexarray[2] < len(Object[indexarray[0]][indexarray[1]])):
            indexarray[3] = 0
                .
                    .
                        .
                         indexarray[n-1] = 0
                         while(indexarray[n-1] < len(Object[indexarray[0]][...]))
                             f(Object[...])
                             indexarray[n-1]+=1
                         .
                     .
                 .
             indexarray[2]+=1
         indexarray[1]+=1
     indexarray[0]+=1
```

Except the problem is that I'm going to have to create a subroutine which generates code itself. Personally I think thats awesome! but... perhaps there is a more "elegant" way of doing this. How should one instead proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to descend through the nested elements of the list, i.e. elements that are themselves a list (or possibly a tuple). This function will traverse all elements of the given list, descending into nested lists and tuples as required:

```
def visit_item(item):
    print 'visit_item(): called on %r' % item

def traverse_list(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            traverse_list(item)
        else:
            visit_item(item)
```

`visit_item()` is called with each item of the list except for nested lists. Here is an example run:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 'hello', 444, ['a', 'b', [7, 7, [3, 2, 1], 7, 7, 7], 'c']]
>>> traverse_list(l)
visit_item(): called on 1
visit_item(): called on 2
visit_item(): called on 3
visit_item(): called on 4
visit_item(): called on 'hello'
visit_item(): called on 444
visit_item(): called on 'a'
visit_item(): called on 'b'
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 3
visit_item(): called on 2
visit_item(): called on 1
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 'c'
```

A small modification to `traverse_list()` allows it to "visit" the actual nested list object, if that is required (I'm not sure about your question):

```
def traverse_list(l):
    for item in l:
        visit_item(item)
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            traverse_list(item)

>>> traverse_list(l)
visit_item(): called on [1, 2, 3, 4]
visit_item(): called on 1
visit_item(): called on 2
visit_item(): called on 3
visit_item(): called on 4
visit_item(): called on 'hello'
visit_item(): called on 444
visit_item(): called on ['a', 'b', [7, 7, [3, 2, 1], 7, 7, 7], 'c']
visit_item(): called on 'a'
visit_item(): called on 'b'
visit_item(): called on [7, 7, [3, 2, 1], 7, 7, 7]
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on [3, 2, 1]
visit_item(): called on 3
visit_item(): called on 2
visit_item(): called on 1
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 7
visit_item(): called on 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about recursion?

```
def traverse_object_dfs(myobject):
    for irun in range(len(myobject)):
        traverse_object_dfs(myobject[irun])

    f(myobject)
```

The problem is, though, that your function `f` is applied in each depth. So you need to find out if you are in the second lowest recursion level. Does your object support something like `ndim`, i.e. you know the dimensionality beforehand? Otherwise we can try to ask if the innermost element supports the `__len__` operation (or alternatively ask if it is an instance of your multidimensional array object, which is what you should do if your innermost elements also support `__len__` to avoid infinite recursions, thanks for pointing that out again in the comments!):

```
def f(myobject):
    print myobject

def traverse_object_dfs(myobject):
    for irun in range(len(myobject)):
        if hasattr(myobject[irun], '__len__'): ## or isinstance(myobject[irun], YourClass) # if innermost elements also support '__len__':
            traverse_object_dfs(myobject[irun])
        else:
            f(myobject[irun])
```

with

```
x = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
traverse_object_dfs(x)
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: String objects have a `__len__` method but should not be processed recursively. In fact your code recurses infinitely (until `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`) whenever a string is present in the input list.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I also alternatively suggested to ask for the type of instance but we don't know the exact class of OP's multidimensional objects :-)

Comment: Surely we know that they are not strings.